# Update the configuration of a field in Solr 6.6.0

Tags: windows, solr

I am using Apache Solr 6.6.0 in order to build a search engine by recursively indexing all files in a folder.

How I do it is as follows: 1) I create an index based on the cloud example. 2) I index all files that are in the given folder.

```
bin\solr start -e cloud -noprompt
java -Dc=gettingstarted -Dauto=yes -Ddata=files -Drecursive=yes -jar example\exampledocs\post.jar <path_to_folder>
```

Later when I search for a query in the user interface, I see that, even though it provides me top matches, it does not provide me the document content. After some research, I found a field named "_text_" and its configuration in the managed-schema file:

```
<field name="_text_" type="text_general" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

As you see, the field is not stored, which I think it is the reason why the response does not provide the content.

Am I on the right track ? If so, how can I edit the configuration of this field ? Should I delete it and create a new one with the same name and with stored=true ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_text_` field is not supposed to be stored because it is used as a "catch all" field. So first, you should check the Solr configuration in order to make sure that it contains only the file content. If it is so, then you could mark that field as stored.

But, generally speaking, files contents are only indexed, not stored, because

- a GUI, in order to let the end user see the content, has some other way to access to the file content (e.g. often static resources like txt files are published in a separate Apache instance, so from a client perspective, it's just a matter of making an HTTP URL)
- it increases your index size a lot

So, in other words: use Solr for search and once you get a given item metadata, use its identifier for going in some other system and "view" the corresponding content. This is the usual* scenario, especially for dealing with unstructured data like txt files

- "usually" doesn't mean it's always valid. There could be some case where you want Solr to do that, or in general there could be some other good reason to mark a field as stored (e.g. highlighting)

Comment: Yes, I realized that, as you said, `_text_` catches from all, so it must contain everything, including the content. However, I feel like editing this field is not the most appropriate way to store the document content. Isn't there any better way to store the content ?

Comment: It depends on what you have to do with the content ;) As I said, often people provides files content through an external http service. Please accept the answer if you think it's what you were looking for

Comment: I am aware that it will increase the index size, but my goal is to see how Solr parses the document and extracts its content. Therefore, providing the content myself would not be useful to my goal. Furthermore, highlighting the matching phrase is another feature I want to add.

Comment: Then you should go for stored="true" ;)